# How do I run additional scripts using the Rubber gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ubuntu, capistrano

I am using the Rubber gem to deploy on Amazon ec2.
It deploys and configures the ubuntu instance well but I need to install additional modules (not ruby modules) on the server. how can I run additional scripts using rubber during the deployment?
A code sample would be appreciated since This is the first time I am doing this kind of thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue with wanting to install the NewRelic server monitor on all of my EC2 instances.  I ended up creating a new role ('newrelic') and adding it to all of my servers.

Making a custom role is straightforward:

1. Create a `config/rubber/deploy-[rolename].rb` (by copying an existing one)

   - Change the task namespace
   - Alter the `:install`, `:bootstrap`, and `:start/:stop/:restart` tasks as required for your module
2. Create a `config/rubber/rubber-[rolename].rb`

   - Add any variables you need to reference in your deploy file
3. If necessary, create a `config/rubber/role/[rolename]` directory and add any required files (such as `[rolename]-upstart.conf`)
4. Add the role to your server(s) by running `cap rubber:add_role`

It's easiest to start by copying an existing role and tweaking it to do what you want.

Jury is still out on whether a custom role is the right way to do this.  It makes some sense for newrelic, since that installs a daemon that needs to get monitored, but it feels very heavyweight for most custom configuration.

Comment: I just want to run a simple script. I placed a few scripts in the deploy-setup.rb but they all run after rubber:install_packages which is before the code is uploaded. I need to run the script after everything is done so I guess all I need to know is the last task being run and then specify it but i don't know what it is

Comment: figured it out all you need to do is declare a task and then use the before/after mechanism to place it after deploy:update_code, however i did use your suggestion too in another place so thanks :)